# Python - show/get jason request

Tags: python, json

why is this not working?

everything works fine but when i put it in some functions it doesnt work

```
import requests

url = 'http://httpbin.org/post'
payload = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}

def getjasonrequest():
    print(url)
    print(payload)


def runjasonrequest():
    r = requests.post(url, data=payload)
    statReason=(r.status_code, r.reason)
    result=(r.text)

def showrequestresult():
    print(statReason+"/n"+result)



getjasonrequest()
runjasonrequest()
showrequestresult()
```

im getting this error

```
   print(statReason)
NameError: name 'statReason' is not definedError: name 'statReason' is not defined
```

this is weird, why isnt it defined?

thanks

Comment: statReason is out of scope so you can't access it outside your function, define a var outside the function and pass it through the arguments

Comment: `statReason` is a local variable where the scope is bound to only the method. Make that a `global` variable or return the variable from the function

Comment: statReason and result is defined in runjasonrequest, it cannot be accessed in showrequestresult, try adding the line,  print(statReason+"/n"+result) to the function runjasonrequest and no need for showrequestresult

Comment: thanks all but that way it will run when page is load, i was putting in a function so i can call the request when never i want and not when the page loads

Answer (score 1):

`statReason` is a local variable where the scope is bound to only the method. Make that a global variable or return the variable from the function. The following returns the values from the method.

```
import requests


url = 'http://httpbin.org/post'
payload = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}

def getjasonrequest():
    print(url)
    print(payload)


def runjasonrequest():
    r = requests.post(url, data=payload)
    statReason=(r.status_code, r.reason)
    result=(r.text)
    return statReason, result

def showrequestresult(statReason, result):
    print(statReason)
    print(result)



getjasonrequest()
statReason, result = runjasonrequest()
showrequestresult(statReason, result)
```

Instead of returning the `statReason`, you can print it in the same method.

Comment: thanks, your method let me learn a little bit more, thanks.
do you know how i can show the getjasonrequest() in ttk.Entry(frmtxtb, width=150, textvariable=()).grid(column=2, row=4, padx=10, pady=10, ipady=75)

Answer (score 0):

Every function gets it's own namespace with variables, as long as you don't pass any variable from the main namespace, it tries to look for it in it's own namespace, therefore the error. You can find more info here https://realpython.com/python-namespaces-scope/

Answer (score 0):

this will work for what i need, thanks

```
import requests

url = 'http://httpbin.org/post'
payload = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
def getjasonrequest():
    print(url)
    print(payload)


def runjasonrequest():
    r = requests.post(url, data=payload)
    statReason=(r.status_code, r.reason)
    result=(r.text)
    print(statReason)
    print(result)



getjasonrequest()
runjasonrequest()
```